# Как отредактировать документ полученный через XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

При получении HTML-странички через AJAX - как работать с ее элементами, а не с текстом разметки?

Например, удалить из полученной страницы `<head>`, добавить класс ее элементу `<h1>`, или вставить еще один элемент в `<body>`.

Comment: Типа-воскрешение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1335342/288409) удаленного его автором (я не успел запостить ответ)... Тут в чуть более общей формулировке. Задачка имхо редкая и решается крайне очевидно (на MDN все практически готовое), но авось кому-нибудь пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

Можно установить свойство [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) объекта запроса в значение `'document'` - тогда текст ответа сервера будет автоматически разобран в DOM, и с ним можно будет работать как с объектом документа:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/html');
xhr.responseType = 'document'; 
xhr.onloadend = evt => {
  // результат берем из свойства `responseXML` (в случае неудачи, там будет `null` вместо объекта `Document`)
  const doc = evt.currentTarget.responseXML; 
  if (!doc) return console.error('Карррамба!'); 

  // удаляем из документа `head`
  doc.head.remove(); 
  // добавляем класс уже существующему элементу 
  doc.querySelector('h1').classList.add('foo'); 
  // вставляем новый элемент в `body`
  const newEl = doc.createElement('p'); 
  newEl.textContent = 'Привет, StackOverflow!'; 
  doc.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterBegin', newEl); 

  console.log(doc.documentElement.outerHTML); 
}; 
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 2):

Если автоматический парсинг ответа сервера (установкой `responseType`) по каким-то причинам неудобен, то можно и самостоятельно разобрать текст разметки в DOM - используя [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/html');
xhr.onloadend = evt => {
  const parser = new DOMParser(); 
  let doc; 
  // в случае неудачи при разборе разметки, будет брошена ошибка (TypeError)
  try {
    doc = parser.parseFromString(evt.currentTarget.responseText, 'text/html'); 
  } catch (err) { return console.error('Карррамба!'); }

  // удаляем из документа `head`
  doc.head.remove(); 
  // добавляем класс уже существующему элементу 
  doc.querySelector('h1').classList.add('foo'); 
  // вставляем новый элемент в `body`
  const newEl = doc.createElement('p'); 
  newEl.textContent = 'Привет, StackOverflow!'; 
  doc.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterBegin', newEl); 

  console.log(doc.documentElement.outerHTML); 
}; 
xhr.send();
```

Этот способ по-моему единственно возможный при выполнении запроса через `fetch`, а не `XMLHttpRequest`.